# Search for a value and add formula to the cell

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet as below ( just an  example, i have many rows in actual file)

```
123 
gl_date
334
inv_date
abc
```

I need to search for 'date' value in all cells and replace the sheet like below

```
123
to_char(gl_date,'yyyy-dd-mm')
334
to_char(inv_date,'yyyy-dd-mm')
abc
```

I really appreciate your inputs. Thanks!

Comment: Press **CTRL+H**, then: **Find**: `gl_date` **Replace with**: `to_char(gl_date,'yyyy-dd-mm')` → Click **[ʀᴇᴘʟᴀᴄᴇ ᴀʟʟ**, then  **Find**: `inv_date` **Replace with**: `to_char(inv_date,'yyyy-dd-mm')` → Click **[ʀᴇᴘʟᴀᴄᴇ ᴀʟʟ]**

Comment: Ctrl +H would replace the entire cell.....i am searching for  cells that have date in their value...and then replace the entire cell with formula including the cell value.

Comment: I don't see dates in your example.  Could you give a more representative example?  Also to type in `code block` you can either indent with 4 spaces or surround the text inline with these "`\``".  Also, is it only those 2 formulas or lots more? Is `123` supposed to be the date?

Comment: That would only search for gl_date, but i might have many rows with the date value...it should apply to all cells that have _date

Comment: By the way, ***Welcome to [so]!***   Be sure to check out the [tour], as well as [ask].  If you're having an issue with something _specific_, please [edit] your questions to provide more information and examples (like described in here: [mcve]) and share what you've tried & where you've looked so far.  Your question might make sense to you but for others who have never seen your data, it's hard to picture what exactly you're working with.  You don't have to share your *actual* data if it's a problem, but something actually representative of it would be great.  I could guess but that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populate a helper column with:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("date",A1)),A1,"to_char("&A1&",'yyyy-dd-mm')")
```

then copy that column and Paste Special, Values over the top of your source (assumed ColumnA).